# Was carbon dioxide also called carbonic acid historically?

Tags: physics, chemistry

I am reading the [classic paper](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1870/JS/JS8702300074#!divAbstract) by Thomas Andrews, in which he discovered the critical point.

The gas he used in his experiments is called by him 'carbonic acid'. By its critical temperature being 31.1 Celsius, I infer that it is actually 'carbon dioxide'.

Do I get it right?

Comment: No. Carbon dioxide is $CO_2$. Carbonic acid is $H_2CO_3$.

Comment: Is it true that chemical symbols should be in roman type, not italic?  $\text{CO}_2$ and not $CO_2$

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  in comments we just use the simplest  Markdown / LaTeX tools. Don't take them as gospel.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: probably. But I do not know how to type subscripts without using TeX/ MathJack.

Comment: My MathJax idiom is something like  C O dollar {} sub 2 dollar, which is terser than something like dollar mathrm{CO}_2 dollar .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The Oxford English Dictionary gives instances of the term "Carbonic acid" meaning CO${}_2$ as old as about 1800.  By 1900, the term "carbonic acid gas" was in common use for CO${}_2$ (my father called it that, 1950-2000, for instance).  More recently it turns out that there is a gaseous phase of H${}_2$CO${}_3$, so "carbonic acid gas" has become an ambiguous term.

Comment: I seem to recall Jules Verne used the term in that manner.

Comment: Yes, in Chapter 9 of _20,000 Leagues Under the Sea_, in the French original and in at least one English translation on Project Gutenberg.